# Getting a 401 error when using Bing API search

Tags: python, bing-api

I went on Microsoft's website and am trying to implement their code they have posted on line which is this:

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'xxxxxxxxxx': '{subscription key}',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'q': 'microsoft',
    'count': '10',
    'offset': '0',
    'mkt': 'en-us',
    'safeSearch': 'Moderate',
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('bingapis.azure-api.net')

conn.request("GET", "/api/v5/news/search?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print(data)
conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

I am getting a 401 error saying "Access denied due ot missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making requests to an API"

I am including the correct subscription key when I am implementing this but am not sure whats wrong.

Comment: According to this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760783.aspx the request header `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` is required.

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760783.aspx the request header `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` is required. Include this where you are defining your headers like so:

```
headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{subscription key}',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your subscription key work on their testing console - https://bingapis.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/56b43f72cf5ff8098cef380a/operations/56f02400dbe2d91900c68553/console